# How to grep a word from a specific line till the end of file?

Tags: linux, shell

How to find a word for eg
Find "abc" starting from line 6 till the end of file ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `awk`, checking both the text and the line number (this script contains only the rule to select lines, it uses the default action which is to print the line):

```
awk 'NR >= 6 && /abc/' inputfile.txt
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax:~> cat inputfile.txt
1 abc
2 def
3 abc
4 xxx
5 yyy
6 abc
7 xyz
8 abc
9 abc

pax:~> awk 'NR >= 6 && /abc/' inputfile.txt
6 abc
8 abc
9 abc
```

Comment: You can omit `{ print }` as that's already hhe default action.

Comment: Force of habit, @tripleee, I've now removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can grep the output of tail command like this.
`tail -n+6 file.txt | grep abc`

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, it's easy to say "ignore lines in this address range" and then grep in the rest.

```sh
sed -n -e '1,5d' -e '/abc/p' file
```

The `-n` option says to not print all lines by default, we then simply delete lines 1 through 5, and then print any matching lines in the remainder.

There's also a block syntax, so you can say

```sh
sed -n '6,${/abc/p;}' file
```

but the precise syntax differs slightly between dialects (I think Linux would not demand a semicolon before the closing brace?) The address range `6,$` selects lines from the sixth through the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Delete (`d`) lines from 1 to 5 (`1,5`); and also delete (the other `d`) lines not (`!`) containing `abc` (`/abc/`):

```sh
sed '1,5d;/abc/!d' input.txt
```